# css change on form field selection

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to do a login & registration form like kickstarer (https://www.kickstarter.com/login)

Can anyone advise where should I be looking at? I'm trying to have the grey border effect to move over when a person clicks on the login or register fields.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add styles to button active state if you want this border on click.

Comment: What do you mean by “the grey border effect”, by “mover over”, by “click” (really just clicking, or focus by tabbing as well), and by “login or register fields” (all fields inside the forms, or just the LOG ME IN! and SIGN ME UP! buttons?)?

Comment: If you are looking for that kickstarter like background & border on section on focusing on input field of that section then you should try that with Jquery focus function change the css of parent container.

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #b4d7f9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use css

```
input:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{border:solid 1px #ccc;}
```